# Computing $\int_{|z|=2} z^n(1 - z)^m\ dz$ for $n,m\in\Bbb Z$

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

[Computing $\int_{|z|=2} z^n(1 - z)^m\ dz$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/762344/757127)

I need help for this question when $m, n$ are negative integers.

Thanks.

Comment: Apply the residue theorem...

Comment: Until now we did not take this theorem....so far we take Cauchy integral formula

Comment: How about Laurent series?  Compute the Laurent series valid in $|z|>1$, then integrate term-by-term.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on the sum $n+m$. If $n+m<-1$ Then the integral is zero. 
\begin{gather}
  f(z)=z^n(1-z)^m\\ 
  I=-2\pi i\underset{z=\infty}{\rm res}f(z)=2\pi i c_{-1}
\end{gather}
There are no poles outside the contour.
Here, $c_{-1}$ is the coefficient of $f(z)$ expansion in the vicinity of the infinity.
The leading behavior of $f(z)$ is
\begin{gather}
  f(z)=(-1)^mz^{n+m}\ \ z\rightarrow\infty. 
\end{gather}
Therefore $c_{-1}=0$ unless $m+n=-1$.

If $m+n=-1$ then:
\begin{gather}
  c_{-1}=(-1)^m\ \Rightarrow\ I=2\pi i(-1)^m
\end{gather}
 P.S.
We have some videos with explanations about contour integrals.
Check out our page:
https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCcOPzqeuB8GTt1zfh6JKbSA

Comment: Nice videos! That being said, self-promo is kinda a no-no here :(

Comment: What are the assumptions on $m$ and $n$ though? If you're allowing only negative integers, then $m + n$ cannot be $-1$. If you're allowing any integers, then it's not true that the residue at infinity is non-zero only for $m + n = -1$.

Comment: Indeed, my blunder. My answer is only true for  $m,\ n\leq 0$. If $m$ and $n$ are strictly negative then the answer is zero, of course.

Answer (score 0):

You said $n,m\lt0$.  By Cauchy's integral formula, I get $2\pi i (1+1)=4\pi i$, when $n=m=-1$.

For other negative values of the exponents, it appears to be more complicated, and I don't see how to do it with CIF.  Perhaps you could use the residue theorem.