# How would Cauchy calculate $\int_{\partial B_1(2i)}\frac{e^{z^2}}{2i-z}dz$?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

Please consider the following curve integral: $$I:=\int_{\partial B_1(2i)}\frac{e^{z^2}}{2i-z}dz$$ where $$B_r(z_0):=\left\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z-z_0|<r\right\}$$

---

Let $\gamma :[a,b]\to\Omega$ denote a piecewise continuously differentiable path in $\Omega$, $\gamma^*:=\gamma([a,b])$ denote its trace, and $f:\gamma^*\to\mathbb{C}$ be continuously $\Rightarrow$ $$\int_\gamma f(z)dz:=\int_a^b\gamma '(t)f(\gamma (t))\;dt$$ is called curve integral of $f$ along $\gamma$.

---

Using the definition above, we can calculate $I$. However, I'm sure there is an easier way to calculate the integral. I thought about [Cauchy's integral theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem) or [Cauchy's integral formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula)
. I'm new to them and still unsure how they can be applied here.

Comment: what is $B_1(2i)$?? ball centered at $2i$??

Comment: When I tried using Cauchy's integral formula, I didn't get zero. Are you sure $I = 0$?

Comment: The integral is not $0$ as can readily be seen by Cauchy's integral formula.

Comment: @SantoshLinkha Sorry for that. I've provided the definition.

Comment: @GitGud I'm sorry if I'd made a mistake. But the main question is how Cauchy's integral theorem/formula can help here. I've updated my question accordingly.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Since $B_r(z)$ is star-shaped for all $r>0,z\in\mathbb{C}$ and the integrand is holomorphic in $B_1(2i)$ and $\partial B_1(2i)$ has a closed piecewise continuously differentiable parameter representation, I've thought $I=0$ would follow from Cauchy's integral theorem for star-domains.

Comment: The integrand is not holomorphic in the ball; it is not even defined at $z = 2i$.

Comment: Yes it is. Care to explain why you think it isn't?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Ouch, you're right. I've mistaken $B_1(2i)$ and $B_2(0)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use Cauchy's integral formula, in the notation of the wikipedia link you provided, set $f(z)=-e^{z^2}$ and $a=2i$. This gives you $I=-\left.2\pi ie^{z^2}\right|_{z=2i}=-2\pi e^{-4}i$.

You mentioned Cauchy's Integral Theorem, but it requires the integrand to be holomorphic. It isn't, so it doesn't contradict the above.

As an added bonus, one can even infer that $z\mapsto -\dfrac{e^{z^2}}{z-2i}$ doesn't have an antiderivative in $\mathbb C$ (or in any neighborhood of $2i$) for if it did, since the path is closed, [the integral would be $0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/757754/55235).

Comment: If $$f(z):=\frac{e^{z^2}}{2i-z}$$ can't we restrict $f$'s domain to $B_1(2i)$? Then, since $B_1(2i)$ is star-shaped, Cauchy's integral theorem would be applicable.

Comment: @oxbadfood You would need $f$ holomorphic in $B_1(2i)$, it isn't even defined there.

Comment: You're absolutely right. As stated in the comments above, I thought about $B_2(0)$ while writing $B_1(2i)$. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @oxbadfood No problem.

Comment: Cauchy's integral theorem doesn't require the domain to be simply connected. It requires that the cycle over which one integrates is null-homologous (the winding number around any point not in the domain is $0$).

Comment: @DanielFischer I confess that that generalization is beyond me. The versions the OP provided/knows aren't that general. In any case I edited out that part of my answer. Thanks.

Comment: @GitGud You've stated that Cauchy's integral theorem requires the integrand to be holomorphic. But as far as I can tell Cauchy's integral formula does require this too. From the wikipedia article: The formula can be applied if $f : U\to\mathbb{C}$ is holomorphic, $D$ is a closed disk which is completely contained in $U$ and $\gamma$ is the circle forming the boundary of $D$. So, if we need $f$ to be holomorphic in $U$ and $D\subset U$, then $f$ must be holomorphic in $D$. What am I missing?

Comment: Illustration: Consider an annulus, $a < \lvert z\rvert < b$. For $a < \rho < b$, let $\kappa_\rho(t) = \rho\cdot e^{it}$ the circle of radius $\rho$. Then $\kappa_R - \kappa_r$ is a null-homologous cycle in the annulus, and Cauchy's integral theorem says $$\int_{\kappa_R - \kappa_r} f(z)\,dz = 0$$ for all $f$ holomorphic in the annulus. In other words, the integral of $f$ over a circle doesn't depend on the radius. If you only have the integral theorem for simply connected domains, that result is harder to come by (in such a geometrically simple situation not much harder, admittedly).

Comment: @0xbadf00d Cauchy's integral formula deals with the integral $$\int_\gamma \frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta-z}\,d\zeta$$ where $f$ is holomorphic in the region enclosed by $\gamma$. The integral theorem deals with $$\int_\gamma f(\zeta)\,d\zeta.$$

Comment: @DanielFischer I've just found that out. At first glance, I didn't noticed that the $f$ in the formula is different from the $f$ in the theorem. But thanks anyway.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you. I will read your comment later.