# Contour integrals for $f(z)= e^{3z}$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Integrate $f(z)=e^{3z}$ along

1. line segment from $(0,0)\to(1,1)$
2. parabola $y=x^2$ from $(0,0)\to(1,1)$
3. circle $|z|=3$ once around its arc (positive $360^o$)

First I parametrized with $z(t)=t+it$ and $z'(t)=1+i$ when $t\in[0,1]$
$$\int_0^1 e^{3(t+it)} (1+i)dt=\frac 13 \Bigg|_0^1 e^{3(t+it)}=\frac 13(e^{3+3i}-1)=-\frac13+\frac 13e^3\cos3+i\frac13e^3\sin3 $$

Or do I have to separate the integral with euler to $\int \operatorname{Re}+i\int\operatorname{Im}$ before I integrate?

In seconds $z(t)=t+it^2$ and $z'(t)=1+i2t$ when $t\in[0,1]$
$$\int_0^1 e^{3(t+it^2)}(t+i2t)dt=\frac 13 \Bigg|_0^1 e^{3(t+it^2)}= \text{same as first one it seems...}$$

For the third I think we need to parametritze $x=r\cos t$ and $y=r\sin t$ so $z'(t)=3\cos t+i3\sin t$ and $z'(t)=-3\sin t+ i3 \cos t$ when $t\in[0,2\pi]$

$$\int_0^{2\pi}e^{9(\cos t + i\sin t)}(-3\sin t+ i3 \cos t)dt=\frac 13 \Bigg|_0^{2\pi} e^{9(r\cos t + i\sin t)}=\frac 13(e^{9\cos 2\pi}-e^{9\cos0})=0$$

Does my work make sense?

Comment: You have made a few mistakes. First one I spot is that you somehow drop $(1+i)$ from your first integral.

Comment: The second integral also is done incorrectly.

Comment: @amcalde No, both are correct.

Comment: It makes sense, ELEC, but it is easier if you don't use the explicit parametrisations, and just apply the fundamental theorem of calculus. Since $e^{3z}$ has a primitive (namely $F(Z) = \frac{1}{3}e^{3z}$ [plus a constant, if you wish], as you know), you can just compute the integral as $F(\text{endpoint}) - F(\text{startpoint})$.

Comment: [What Daniel Fischer said](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/757744/analytic-fz-has-fz-as-derivative-implies-int-gamma-fz-dz-0-f/757754#757754).

Comment: That's convenient. I have a bad habit of just doing mechanical calculations before trying simpler methods. thanks @DanielFischer