# Line integral of a conservative fields over a circle

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, vectors, polar-coordinates, line-integrals

I need to show that moving the curve to a simply connected region, the integral of the field over the curve will be $0$.

> Given $F(x, y) = ((-y)/(x^2+y^2 ), (x/(x^2+y^2 ))$, and $γ$ circle of radius $1$ centered at $(2, 0)$; i.e., $γ ( t ) = (2 +  \cos t ,\sin t )$, $0 ≤ t ≤ 2π$. Note that $γ$ is entirely contained in the open half-plane $x > 0$, the half-plane is simply connected, and $F$ is defined everywhere in the half-plane.

How do I show that $$∮F \cdot ds = 2∮_0^{2\pi}(1+2\cos φ)/(5+4\cosφ)\,dφ$$ and subsequently 
 $$∮_0^{\pi}F \cdot ds = π −π = 0 $$
(I know this is true because each path taken is independent)

I tested $∂M/∂y=∂N/∂y$ for conservative field, it checks out. Then I derive the potential functions.
However, it seems I need to use the polar coordinates, since I have a circle with points $(3,0), (2,1), (1,0), (2,-1)$  on the $x$-axes and $y$-axes.
I just don’t know how to implement what I know.

HELP PLEASE!!

Comment: See [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation). Also, you are giving a list of things to show instead of asking a question. What is unclear to you about these exercises?

Comment: I was able to edit the question..

Comment: Okay, I edited it a bit more. So, the first part invites you to plug $\gamma$ into the formula $\int_0^{2\pi} F(\gamma)\cdot \gamma'(\varphi)\,d\varphi$. After simplification, this should give that integral with $\cos \varphi$. That the integral evaluates to zero follows from the fact that $F$ is conservative in a simply connected domain containing $\gamma$.

Comment: Looks so much better, thank you..

Comment: @Lilacfluer Can you find a potential or not? This isn't clear to me from your question.

Comment: I did, $-tan^-1$(x/y) + C...I think

Comment: @Lilacfluer It doesn't even matter what it is, all that matters is that it exists. To understand why, see [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/757744/analytic-fz-has-fz-as-derivative-implies-int-gamma-fz-dz-0-f/757754#757754) answer of mine. (It's from complex analysis, but the idea/symbols used on the proof are the same).

Comment: @GitGud  I saw it, thanks, but that’s just the general form, which I get...So I’m trying to apply that to the example above, but struggling to apply the general formula

Comment: @Lilacfluer Let's see. So you understand that $\displaystyle ∮F \cdot \mathrm ds=0$. You just don't understand why $\displaystyle ∮F \cdot ds = 2\int \limits_0^{2\pi}(1+2\cos φ)/(5+4\cosφ)\,dφ$, is that it?

Comment: well... I think the circle has to be split in half. I’ll try to work out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19097/discussion-between-lilacfluer-and-git-gud).

Comment: @Lilacfluer I can't join you in chat now. Going off. Good luck.