# Contour integral $\int_c {(z - {i^2})dz} $ over the line segment from $0$ to $1+2i$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Hello can someone help me to solve this problem?

Evaluate the integral where $c$ is the straight line segment joining $0$ and $1+2i$.

$$\int\limits_c {(z - {i^2})dz} $$

Comment: Use [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/757744/analytic-fz-has-fz-as-derivative-implies-int-gamma-fz-dz-0-f/757754#757754).

Comment: Also note that the problem is ill-posed due to the use of 'the' in 'the straight line' when there are two straight lines connecting both points.

Answer (score 5):

Parametrize $z=t(1+2i)$ to get
$$
\int_c(z-i^2)\,\mathrm{d}z=\int_0^1\overbrace{(t(1+2i)+1)}^{(z-i^2)}\overbrace{(1+2i)\,\mathrm{d}t}^{\mathrm{d}z}
$$