# Prove that $\oint _{|z|=R} (f-g)' dz = 0$ (Residue Theorem)

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus

I know that $f$ and $g$ have a pole or order $k$ in $z=0$.
$f-g$ is holomorph in $\infty$.

I need to prove that:

$$\oint_{|z|=R} (f-g)' dz = 0$$

Any help?

Note: $f$ and $g$ only have a singularity in $z=0$

Comment: Integral of $(f-g)'$  over a closed loop is zero... because $(f-g)'$ has an antiderivative...

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: [What user147263 said](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/757744/analytic-fz-has-fz-as-derivative-implies-int-gamma-fz-dz-0-f/757754#757754).

Answer (score 1):

As Git Gud alluded to in their comment, simply parameterise the curve and calculate the integral directly. The usual parameterisation is $\gamma:[0,2\pi]\rightarrow\mathbb C:\ t\mapsto Re^{it}$. Letting $h=f-g$, we have
$$\oint_Ch'(z)\ \mathrm dz=\int_0^{2\pi}h'(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)\ \mathrm dt=\int_0^{2\pi}(h\circ\gamma)'(t) \mathrm dt\\=(h\circ\gamma)(2\pi)-(h\circ\gamma)(0)=h(R)-h(R)=0.$$

Answer (score 0):

If $h$ is holomorphic, then $h'$ exists and is holomorphic. If $h$ is holomorphic, then $\oint_C h dz = 0$ for all circles $C$. Take $h= f-g$, $(f-g)'$ respectively.

Comment: No, the exercise is not so stupid haha. $f-g$ is holomorphic in $z=\infty$

Comment: What does "holomorphic in $z=\infty$" mean? I know of holomorphic on an open set.

Comment: This isn't quite true. If $h$ is holomorphic on a region $D$ and $C$ is a closed simple curve entirely within $D$, then $\oint_Ch(z)\ \mathrm dz=0$. But $h=(f-g)'$ is not holomorhpic at $z=0$.

Comment: @Jason why is that? the OP did not say that $f-g$ is not holomorphic at $z=0$. He said that it is holomorphic at $\infty$ which I presume, maybe mistakenly, that it's entire. For example, take $f=g=\frac{1}{z}$

Comment: Well fine, it is not *necessarily* holomorphic at $z=0$. Your example doesn't change the fact that we do not know for sure that $(f-g)'$ is holomorphic at $z=0$, so we cannot use Cauchy's theorem.